# Angular.js api Запросы

Tags: angularjs

Подскажите как делать с ангуляра запросы на API?
get post put delete? погуглил но судя по всему там для старых версий статьи

Comment: Что значит для старых версий? Насколько я представляю, в этой части там принципиальных изменений не было. Или в вопросе говорится об Angualar 2? В таком случае это надо явно указать.

Answer (score 4):

Запросы на API - это обычные запросы. Для этого в ангуляре есть два пути

1. [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) - сервис позволяющий делать ajax запросы. Имеет такие методы как [get](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get), [post](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post) и т.д.
   Пример:

   ```
   // Simple GET request example:
   $http({
     method: 'GET',
     url: '/someUrl'
   }).then(function successCallback(response) {
       // this callback will be called asynchronously
       // when the response is available
     }, function errorCallback(response) {
       // called asynchronously if an error occurs
       // or server returns response with an error status.
     });
   ```
2. [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) - сервис, надстройка над сервисом $http, упрощающий работу с  RESTful API
   Пример:

   ```
   var User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'});
   User.get({userId:123}, function(user) {
     user.abc = true;
     user.$save();
   });
   ```

Comment: А код можно или слишком много будет?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, тривиальные примеры из справки скопировать?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, добавил

Comment: Спасибо ) Любой код для кого-нибудь тривиален.