# Как использовать фабрику в контроллере?

Tags: angularjs

Сделал такую фабрику

```
//Factories  

Versions = app.factory('Versions', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('http://webfather.ru:3000/api/links/', {
      domainid : '@domainid'
    });
  })
```

Пытаюсь использовать ее в контроллере

```
//Controllers

app.controller('multiCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
$scope.Versions = Versions.query({domainid : '56fa4eb4a93200ca38f4be8a'});
alert($scope.Versions); 

}]);
```

И получаю ошибку **TypeError: Versions.query is not a function**

что делаю не правильно?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Angular.js api Запросы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/507243/angular-js-api-%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b)

Comment: @d-side, до хоть до посинения минусуй, там ответа нет в том топике

Comment: Значит, предыдущий вопрос задан плохо и подлежит редактированию, а не дублированию. Вопрос ваш же, чем вас ответ оттуда не устраивает, вы не сказали.

Comment: @d-side, это совсем другой вопрос, тут хочу узнать почему ошибка в моем коде, если лень читать весь текст то не пишите вообще ничего

Comment: Вопрос следует из него: "Как передавать запросы get, put, post, delete?", только это решение не использует ни одного из вариантов, описанных там. Поэтому и отметка дублирования, что вы делаете запрос совсем неправильно и надо смотреть ответ именно к тому вопросу, потому что он решает ту же задачу. У меня всё.

Comment: @D-side, вообще не дубликат.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что все методы из модуля [`angular.module`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module) возвращают *объект модуля* фактически самого себя.

Поэтому приведенный код в вопросе в корне неверен.

Для использования созданной фабрики ее нужно добавить в зависимости контроллера(список параметров)

```
app.controller('multiCtrl', ['$scope','Versions', function ($scope, Versions) {
```

Comment: Ну наконец то нормальный ответ, а не злобные придирки) Спасибо огромное, смотрел видеоуроки на английском(не зная его), про фабрики там вообще не слова, поэтому такой гемор у меня. А вообще Вы бы смогли меня платно проконсультировать по некоторым вопросам?

Comment: так что?) получится?

Comment: @SdafsFasafs, что получится?

Comment: ^
 
платные косультации?

Comment: @SdafsFasafs, :-D вас чем-то не устраивает формат вопрос-ответ? :)

Comment: очень долго + больше почему то ищут проблемы в вопросе вместо того чтобы его понять, хотя для понятия надо напрячь мозги совсем немного.. Может тут за придирки к вопросу рейтинг дают поэтому не знаю))

Comment: @SdafsFasafs, ну просто по внимательнее с вопросами, собственно в текущем вопросе: _Как передавать запросы get, put, post, delete?_ - но проблема, то не в этом. На это и указывают. Сначала надо определиться - о чем собственно должен быть вопрос, например тут можно изменить вопрос на: как использовать сервис в контроллере и отношение было бы совсем другое.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37803/discussion-between-sdafs-fasafs-and-grundy).